# iphone blue tooth connection

Tags: iphone

could i connect  iPhone and collect data from other bluetooth device  (it may be iphone , ipod, nokia or other blue tooth device, like PC and so on.) from my own application. ?

if it is possible which way is the easiest  . like GameKit framework ?

pls help me

Answer (score 1):

With the SDK the `GameKit` framework is your only choice.

Comment: @jaleel: Only to another iPhone/iPod Touch. To your own app.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to low-level access to Bluetooth devices, also knowing apple and their policy on connecting external devices to their iPods, it would take some kind of chip and licensing deal for a vendor to be able to connect their device to an iPhone. So I am guessing that not all bluetooth devices will be abble to connect to your iPhone